# I get the error int cannot be converted to boolean?

Tags: java

So here is my code, it's very simple I'm kinda learning java and reached the part of if/else statements. But every time I try to run this code, I get the error that int cannot be converted to boolean. Also, if anyone knows a good Java tutorial, that would help a lot.
This is the code:

```
package learn;
public class Learn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int user = 19;

        if (user => 19){
            System.out.println("You are 19!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You are not 19!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: typo: `if (user >= 19){`...

Answer (score 1):

The Java *greater than or equal to* operator is >=, not =>.

Where you did:

```
if (user => 19) ...
```

You should have done:

```
if (user >= 19) ...
```

If you ever have questions regarding this, check the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) first.

Answer (score 1):

It should be written like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int user = 19;

        if (user == 19){
        System.out.println("You are 19!");
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("You are not 19!");
        }


    }
```

You had the operator wrong in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake lies in the fact that in java greater than or equal sign is written like this`>=` not like this `=>`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the '>=' relational operator.

```
x >= y
```

Greater than or equal to: True if x is greater than or equal to y, otherwise false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int user = 19;

    if (user >= 19) {
        System.out.println("You are 19!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You are not 19!");
    }
}
```

You are 19!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int user = 16;

    if (user >= 19) {
        System.out.println("You are 19!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You are not 19!");
    }
}
```

You are not 19!